# Backbone Collection from JSON file won't pass to the view

Tags: json, backbone.js, view, collections

I've been trying to figure this out for hours, but can't seem to get it working. The json file being loaded in the "Friends" collection won't populate in the view.

```
var Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "name": "Unknown",
        "job": "Unknown"
    }
});
var friend = new Friend({

});

var Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Friend,
    url: '/friends.json',
    initialize: function() {
        this.fetch();
    }
});
var friends = new Friends();

var FriendsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    template: _.template('<li><%= name %> is a  <%= job %></li>'),
    render: function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    }
});
var friendsView = new FriendsView({ model: friend });

friendsView.render();
$('#here').html(friendsView.el);
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Timmy",
    "job": 'Sky Diver'
},
{
    "name": "Michael",
    "job": 'Hat salesman'
}
```

I can see in the console that the json file is loading via ajax.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You aren't passing your `friends` collection to your view. Does the view populate with the `unknown is a unknown`?

Comment: If I put "var friendsView = new FriendsView({ collection: friends });" it gives me a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toJSON' of undefined" error.

Comment: Yes, it currently populates with unknown is a unknown.

Comment: Do you expect to have a separate view for each friend or display the collection of friends in a single view?

Comment: a list of friends in a single view.

Comment: @fbynite I've added my code to a JS bin, if you don't mind taking a look: http://jsbin.com/EJIRaXI/2/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Friend = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        "name": "Unknown",
        "job": "Unknown"
    }
});

var Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Friend,
    //url: '/friends.json',
});

var friends = new Friends([{
    "name": "Timmy",
    "job": 'Sky Diver'
},
{
    "name": "Michael",
    "job": 'Hat salesman'
}]);

var FriendsView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<li><%= name %> is a  <%= job %></li>'),
    render: function(){
        this.collection.each(function(model){
            this.$el.append(this.template(model.toJSON()));
        }, this)
    }
});
var friendsView = new FriendsView({ el: $('#here'), collection: friends });

friendsView.render();

// though for fetching the remote data you'd want..
// friends.fetch({ success: friendsView.render })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/lecstor/yrZgH/

Comment: thanks, it's displaying the list of data in the collection. I can't seem to figure out how to get the remote data to populate to the view. Sorry, this is not obvious to me as I am new with Backbone.

Comment: I think backbone sync is choking on your json.. not sure why no error though. try making it an array. hmm.. have my changes overwritten your jsbin? sorry about that.. it actually seems to be working, though the actual content isn't displaying.. can't work that out.